# Make a basic web page, only purpose of the web page is to be able to upload background image locally and display it

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, background-image

Make a basic web page, only purpose of the web page is to be able to upload background image and display locally when going to that address in the browser.

For example, say I have this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500" />
        <input type="file" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, what next? Here is what I want to do:

I click the upload button.
It uploads to my own computer at the following address:

```
file://C:\dummyfolder\images\
```

See what I'm getting at? I do real web design online but this is different. I got this idea and now I wanna do it. Please help!

I can think of someone who did this before. Google does it on their site. When you go to google.com you can choose a background image to display on Google. It stores the image locally on your computer. I want to do that, just on a web page that is stored locally, and the web page is stored locally at the url:

```
file://C:\dummyfolder\dummypage.html
```

It could be PHP too, it doesn't matter. It will never be accessed anywhere except locally within my own computer so it does not have to be too complicated.

I want the littlest code possible. Just an upload link and then it stores the image on my computer and automatically displays as a background on that html page whenever I visit it. If I upload another image it changes to the new image that is also stored locally or maybe it could replace the old image? Dunno.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Install a webserver on your local machine, then you can do whatever you want .. however obsure O_o

Comment: no, no. that's not what I want. It is an html page but not a web page.
I need it to be entirely independent. Just that one html or php file and that is All.

Comment: You want [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/html5_local_storage.htm) (link contains a tutorial with a working app). Set a (local storage) `backgroundFile` variable when your form submits. As the file is always stored on your PC, all you need to store is the path to it. Check that variable on load, then use that value. See the answer left by [MrGlass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8440082/50049), which is basically what I would have answered, hence the comment only to supplement it.

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly certain that a web page cannot store (upload is the wrong term here, as the image never leaves your computer) an image on the clients PC.

Sites that allow you to set a background image generally store the image on their webserver & then store information pointing to which background is yours in either a cookie or database. Twitter, google, and many more use this method.

You might be able to use some HTML5 features to store the image locally using the new local storage options in HTML5. You can pick through the W3C docs here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

Comment: ok you are right. "upload" was the wrong word. "Store" the file on click then. How do I do it? thanks in advance.

Comment: NOTE: I am using Google Chrome. Remember that Google Chrome itself is a resource as well. I will build an extension to do this. So, how do I do it? I know how to build extensions. I just don't know how to do the answer to the question.

Comment: As i said, only possible way I can think of is the HTML5 local storage features. I haven't had an opportunity to look into those yet, so your on your own there.

Comment: Spot on :) Yes, he could easily do this with local storage since the file is known to exist on the same machine. @asdfsdf I left a comment under your question with a specific tutorial.